# Add custom star to Gmail Message using Gmail REST API or Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

How can you use the Gmail REST or Apps API to add a custom star to a message? Is there an alternate label name we can use for the Gmail REST API? Is it even possible from the Google Apps Script API?

**Context**
A Gmail user can change their settings to customize which stars they want to use. These used to be called "superstars" named after the Labs feature that introduced them. It continues to appear when working them, like the asset URL: [...superstars/star_lit_green_check3.png](https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/superstars/star_lit_green_check3.png).

[image: Custom stars]

**Gmail REST API**
The Gmail REST API does not provide an endpoint to set a custom star. You can star or unstar by using the [User.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) endpoint to add or remove the `STARRED` label. There doesn't seem to be any documentation indicating what other labels are available for full set of stars.

[image: Result from using the Gmail REST API to add the STARRED label]

Since the documentation doesn't offer clues how to set custom stars, inspecting the network requests using Gmail gives us a lead.

[image: Inspecting network requests shows superstar label form value]

The "sslbl" follows the pattern of  where the prefix is `^ss_`, the type is `s` for a star or `c` for the custom types, and the first letter of the color. Working through them all gives us the list:

Stars: `^ss_sy, ^ss_so, ^ss_sr, ^ss_sp, ^ss_sb, ^ss_sg`
Custom: `^ss_cr, ^ss_co, ^ss_cy, ^ss_cg, ^ss_cb, ^ss_cp`

A little research later, and you'll end up with:

- A list showing the [search queries and their shorthand for superstars](https://googlesystem.blogspot.ca/2008/07/gmail-superstars.html)
- The [similar shorthand](https://googlesystem.blogspot.ca/2007/05/shortcuts-for-special-gmail-labels.html#gsc.tab=0) for other common locations

Unfortunately these internal labels aren't recognized by the REST API. Testing another internal `^`-prefixed label also fails, suggesting that you can't use these here. Notice how the `CATEGORY_FORUMS` label in the screenshot above is applied to the message. The corresponding `^smartlabel_group` label fails.

[image: Internal labels are not recognized]

~~

*Edit*: Based on @TarunLalwani's suggestion, I've tried `User.messages.modify` using a URL encoded label. For `^ss_sy`, that is encoded as `%5Ess_sy`. Here's the result:

[image: Encoded internal labels are also not recognized]

~~

Another barrier - using [Users.labels.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list) doesn't include any labels related to the custom stars in the system or user labels.

*What label name can we use from the Gmail REST API?*

**Google Apps Script Gmail API**

This API falls short:

- You can only [star](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#star())/unstar messages
- The API limits you to getting [user-created labels](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getUserLabels())
- Using `GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("^ss_sy")` returns `null`

There doesn't seem to be a way to access the internal labels. *Is it even possible with this limited API?*

Comment: Have you tried with `%5E` instead of `^`?

Comment: Good idea @TarunLalwani but no luck from the REST API.
I'll update the question to reflect that.