# How to set / get color stars for messages in gmail via REST api

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

We can star the message using below API

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{messageId}/modify

{
  "addLabelIds": [
    "STARRED"
  ]
}
```

But the above api sets star for the specified message. I want to set color star like red star to message.

How can I do that

Comment: I'm not sure how to set a "super star" with the Gmail API, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157723/unable-to-search-for-specific-coloured-star-superstars-using-advanced-search-i) might help in querying for it.

Comment: I've asked this question with a bit more research here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981794/add-custom-star-to-gmail-message-using-gmail-rest-api-or-google-apps-script.
Good luck!